# How to replace a list of words into a word document automatically?

Tags: dictionary, ms-word

I have a custom Dictionary I have made in word and it is about 200 words. it contain the common errors that some people mistype and it didn't exist in the original word dictionary.

how to replace any word in my list in any document automatically. I mean whenever word see the wrong word it replace it with the one existed in my list.

I don't want to auto correct every single word every time I open a document.

Answer (score 0):

I used to to something like this some years ago with Windows scripting host and OLE.
So today this would be kind of old fashioned but I bet it still works. However it requires you to have Word installed.

Since Word is remote controllable via COM, you could use nearly every programming language (C++ works natively but is a native nightmare) to remote control it. Then it would be easy to traverse thru and replace the words. Or invoke the search and replace function multiple times.

200 words can easily be held in your source code.

As the "included" feature Windows Scripting host is ok - you can choose between JScript and VB. Just create a .js file and by default it should be executed with WSH. But why don't you use macros (Essentially the same functionality - only seen thru the Word -GUI). But you may also use C# or Delphi....